# "jeder einzige" vs. "jeder einzelne" bezogen auf abstrakte Dinge

Tags: difference

Welche Variante ist richtig, wenn von abstrakten Dingen die Rede ist? Z.B.:

> Er ist bei *jedem einzigen/einzelnen* Test durchgefallen.

Oder geht beides?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Jedem einzigen* ist ein Widerspruch in sich, denn *jeder* impliziert, dass es um mehrere Dinge geht, *einzig* hingegen, es ginge nur um ein einziges Ding.

Answer (score 2):

> Er ist bei jedem Test durchgefallen.

Da man in Tests schlecht gruppenweise durchfallen kann macht das *einzelnen* wenig Sinn.

Wie Janka richtig schreibt, ist 'einzigen' Test falsch. Auch wenn ein einziger Test die Gesamtheit der Tests ist, an denen jemand teilnimmt, bildet man diese Kombination nicht.

> Der Dozent hat jeden einzelnen Studenten beleidigt.

Das könnte man sagen, da er auch alle gemeinsam als Gruppe beleidigt haben könnte.

Es ist aber nicht ungewöhnlich, dass *jeden einzelnen ...* gedankenlos wie eine Verstärkung eingesetzt wird.